# Django Rest Framework filter on the base of JSONField nested objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, drf-queryset

I'm working on a Project using Python(3), Django(1.11) and DRF in which I have to filter the data on the base of a `json` object field which is saved as `JSONFIELD` in db model.

Here's what I have tried:

```py
# model.py

from django.db import models
import jsonfield

class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    props = jsonfield.JSONField()
    repo = jsonfield.JSONField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

```py
# serializers.py

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    props = serializers.JSONField()
    repo = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = EventModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

```py
# JSON object
{
  "id":4633249595,
  "type":"PushEvent",
  "props":{
    "id":4276597,
    "login":"iholloway",
    "avatar_url":"https://avatars.com/4276597"
  },
  "repo":{
    "id":269910,
    "name":"iholloway/aperiam-consectetur",
    "url":"https://github.com/iholloway/aperiam-consectetur"
  },
  "created_at":"2016-04-18 00:13:31"
}
```

```py
# views.py

class PropsEvents(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        print(self.request.parser_context['kwargs']['id'])
        queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(data__props__id=self.request.parser_context['kwargs']['id'])
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
       return obj
```

> It should return the MyModel records by `props ID` and should be able to
>   return the JSON array of all the `MyModel objects` where the `props ID` by
>   the GET request at `/mymodel/props/<ID>`. If the requested `props` does not
>   exist then HTTP response code should be 404, otherwise, the response
>   code should be 200. The JSON array should be sorted in ascending order
>   by MyModel ID.

When I sent a request to this view, it returns an error:

```sh
> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'id' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.
> [18/Feb/2019 10:37:39] "GET /events/actors/2790311/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16210
```

So, how can I filter the objects based on the `id of props`?

Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already asked the very same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744169/django-rest-framework-retrieve-nested-jsonfield-with-filters?noredirect=1#comment96273442_54744169

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature your are looking for is possible, unfortunately it is not that straightforward. As far as I know it is not supported by the `jsonfield` package, but instead you would have to use [Postgres as your database backend and use its internal JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield). I think you can choose one of the following:

- switch to `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` and use Postgres    as your db backend in all enviroments (and then support such lookups)
- make the data follow certain schema and change the JSONField to a separate model and table
- use a hybrid storage solution with a dedicated solution for JSON documents
- extract the fields you need to query against to your model - enabling the querying, but keeping the unstructured data in the JSONField.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    props = jsonfield.JSONField()
    props_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    repo = jsonfield.JSONField()
    repo_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

And then set the id values manually or in the `save()` of the model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.repo_id = self.repo.get("id")
    self.props_id = self.props.get("id")
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: can we achieve this with `sqlite3` because it's the requirements to use `sqlite3`?

Comment: I'm afraid not, this is natively supported only by postgres, hence why it is not in main django fields. To stay with sqlite you will need to try one of the others solutions, or e.g. extract the fields you need to query against to a separate model field. I'll update the answer with this idea.

Comment: Hi @mfrackowiak, on creating new object the `porps_id` is not adding automatically from `self.props.get("id")`, and when I remove the ` null=True`  the it's required `props_id` from input object. I can't change the input object structure, so how can I force it to add `props_id` from `save()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
```

Instead of

```
import jsonfield
```

And after that I think everything should work correctly

Comment: now it returns `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.` for `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`

Comment: sqlite3 is not so good for production, this solution works if you use postgresql as a database and do not work for other databases